# Positioning a gun at a constant place

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to position my gun the way most fps games position it, 
for example like this:

[image]

But I'm having a problem when I try to position and rotate it with the player. The gun doesn't rotate well and doesn't have the same position always.

Is there a way to keep a gun in the same position and make it rotate well with the player?

But my main problem is the position of the gun i need it to stay in one place like in every fps, when i start the game and pick a gun it spawn in diffrent location on the screen Because of the rotation.

Here's is the code that I am trying to use:

```
GameObject temp = GameObject.Find(gameObject.name);
playerGuns[keyPress] = Instantiate(temp, Player.transform.position 
                       + new Vector3(-2f, 3f, 4f), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
playerGuns[keyPress].name = gameObject.name;
playerGuns[keyPress].tag = gameObject.tag;
playerGuns[keyPress].transform.parent = Player.transform;
playerGuns[keyPress].transform.rotation.SetLookRotation(Player.transform.position);
```

Comment: Make the gun a part of the player gameobject and when you rotate the player object the gun will always rotate with it.

Comment: Yes.. but the position is still the problem.

Comment: Whats the problem? The way it looks on the screen? Is the gun actually rotating poorly?

Comment: Yes but the main problem is the position of the gun I need it to stay in on the same place and only move with the player and rotate with it

Comment: With all the comments, I don't think anyone understood your issue. Do you mind proving a link to gif or video of the issue?

Comment: Lets start by removing `playerGuns[keyPress].transform.rotation.SetLookRotation(Player.transform.position);`  try turning and seeing if the weapon stays in the same place.

Comment: that solve one problem, but how do I position it like the picture I try to use vector but because of the rotation the position change when i pick it.

Comment: What solves what problem?

Comment: The bad rotation.

Comment: Alright now lets create a public Vector3 and set the rotation to that something like `playerGuns[keyPress].transform.eulerAngles = determineEulerRotation;`  Only do this when you first create the weapon

Comment: Thanks now the rotation is fixed but what about the start position of the gun

Comment: Do the same thing you did for the rotation, but name the vector an offset vector and then when you create it instead of doing `Player.transform.position + new Vector3(-2f, 3f, 4f)` do `Player.transform.position + offset`  I will write up an answer when I get home explaining the issues and my "recommendations" for doing something like this for different weapon types...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright here is the answer I promised:

First issue was with how you were setting your rotation, `SetLookRotation` takes in 2 parameters, `Vector3 view`, and `Vector3 up`  the second is defaulted to `Vector3.up`.  You were passing in the player.transform.position, for the "view"  which is the direction you want transform to look in.  Think of it like this, if I am far east facing west, my weapon will face east... (That is assuming the SetLookRotation normalizes it.)  this is because my actual position is east, from some arbitrary origin. Something you could have used would have been `player.transform.forward`.

To spawn an object and have it have the same relative rotation and and position you can use `Instantiate` like you have in your original code.  There are Several versions of [instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

In the comments I said to give yourself an offsetPosition and a eulerAngle, but this can be quite troublesome if you have multiple weapons.  I mentioned I would give a recommendation for how I would set this up for multiple weapons... So here yea go.

---

Scriptable Objects,

In Unity you can create this objects to store information about a particular object, so for example a "Weapon" object can look like this:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Weapon", menuName = "Weapon")]    
public class WeaponObject : ScriptableObject {
    public string objectName = "New Weapon";
    public Vector3 offSetPosition;
    public Vector3 startOffsetRotation;
    public float fireRate;
    // Using a gameObject to store the weapon model so you can technical
    // store the firing point.
    public GameObject weaponModel;  
}
```

You can create a new object now by right-clicking in your asset directory and going to create->weapon.  Once you have done this you can rename the object it made, and the inspector will show all the public fields for this object you can modify.

With this you can create multiple weapons, and store their data in like a WeaponManager, that spawns every weapon.  with something like:

```
WeaponObject weapon = WeaponManager.getWeapon(keyPress);
playerGuns[keyPress] = Instantiate(weapon.weaponModel, Player.transform.position + weapon.offsetPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
playerGuns[keyPress].name = weapon.objectName;
playerGuns[keyPress].transform.parent = Player.transform;
playerGuns[keyPress].transform.eulerAngles = weapon.startOffsetRotation;
if(player.weaponScript != null) {
   // we can have a single script for all of our weapons, and the WeaponObject
   // will control its firerate, which projectiles it fires, etc.
   player.weaponScript.setWeapon(weapon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is the answer that i'm Looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
playerGuns[keyPress].transform.parent = Player.transform;
```

This line might be causing a problem. If you are parenting your gun to the players transform then it will follow the player. But it sounds like you want it to follow the camera?

try:

```
 playerGuns[keyPress].transform.parent = Camera.main.transform;
```

Comment: In a FPS the camera, and the player are typically at the same position, and possibly the same transform...

Comment: Yes I'm assuming so but it sounds like Netanel's problem is based on rotation? for example if his character is strafing to the left the ideal behaviour would be for the gun to keep facing forward. However it may follow the player objects new 'forward' and face left.  I would have thought the camera would be a better parent in a 3D FPS.  It depends on the structure of the player character controller.    It would be much easier if we could see an example of the problem behaviour

Comment: same argument applies, the rotation of the player is typically the same as the camera, if they are not the same transform... unless you know of a FPS that the camera and player arent the same transform?

Comment: also if you are strafing left... you are still facing the same forward you are moving left.  (Lets not get transform.forward confused with our velocity direction)

Comment: Ah yes i see what you mean. I don't think the camera and the player would have the same transform.rotation though. Otherwise the player would lean back horizontal when they looked up

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful answer provided by reddit user Mathias9807:

> Many games will clear the depth buffer before drawing the gun model.
> This will prevent the gun model from clipping through geometry but it
> can look a bit weird when standing near a wall:
> [image: but it can look a bit weird when standing near a wall.]
>
> If you just want to render an object sticking to the camera you should
> just get rid of the view matrix (Assuming you're using model-, view-
> and projection matrices).

Explanation: Normally when you are using a view matrix (the camera matrix),the objects in the scene are being translated relative to the magnitude of the cameras position vector, and rotating by its yaw and pitch, which gives the illusion of a camera moving in a 3D space, but really there is no camera, just the objects in the scene that scale, and translate in in relation to the values defined for the camera.

So, when you remove that camera matrix for an object, the cameras position now has no influence on the models position, or put another way, the model does not move relative to the camera anymore but moves congruently with the camera.